# AWS Cognito AdminInitiateAuth all custom scopes are missing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have a cognito user pool, configured with AWS::Cognito::UserPoolResourceServer with lists of scopes, all these scopes are enabled on UserPoolClient->AllowedOAuthScopes. When I go through UI authentication, the token contains a list of scopes

```
 "scope": "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin labs-mymoney-bills-api/view labs-mymoney-bills-api/edit openid profile labs-mymoney-bills-api/pay email",
```

for testing purposes I use adminInitiateAuth to fetch a token, with following params

```
  var authParams = {
        AuthFlow: 'ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',
        ClientId: 'myclientid',
        UserPoolId: 'myuserpool',
        AuthParameters: {
            USERNAME: 'myuser',
            PASSWORD: 'herpassword'
        }

    };
```

The result token's scope looks like that

```
"scope": "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin",
```

Obviously, when I try to authenticate with my API endpoint that has defined scope, it is always unauthorized.

Is it a bug, or I'm doing something wrong, or have unrealistic expectations?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is not a bug and is by design. The Cognito Custom scopes will only be returned when you authenticate via the Oauth endpoints. When you create a Cognito domain, Cognito will create a Hosted UI/authorization server which exposes the Oauth endpoints. Signing in via these endpoints will return the custom scopes in the access token when configured correctly.

Signing in via initiate Auth or admin initiate Auth is not via the Oauth endpoints so the Oauth custom scopes will not be included in the token.

I hope that helps. You can test this by setting up the HostedUI and signing in. The token you will receive should contain the scopes.

Comment: Thanks, however, I find it is wired, what is the point of admin auth token, if it doesn't give you access to your things...

Comment: What are you referring to when you say ‘admin Auth token’? The aws.cognito.signin.user.admin scope allows you to make calls to Cognito to update user attributes etc. With out this scope, you would use the tokens to authorize requests to your own resource server or APIGateway as an example.

Comment: Allowing the flexibility to do this via CLI/boto3 would make a big difference. There are so many limitations with their hosted UI (localization, flow customization, UI layout, etc.). We're currently using Amplify to make our own UI which has led up to this issue. We have our own API Gateway handling the auth portions but cannot generate access tokens with our client defined scopes, even though the initiate auth functions take in the client ID as an input.

Comment: Having the same issue. The Auth class (and also the new Authenticator component) does not have a way to retrieve a token with all of the scopes as requested when Auth is configured. Any luck with this ?

Comment: >>I hope that helps. You can test this by setting up the HostedUI and signing in. The token you will receive should contain the scopes.

What if you want to connect via a rest client?  I've tried having the rest client do the form post but the endpoint keeps giving a 400 bad request