# Getting Access Tokens with Cognito using Username and Password

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, oauth, amazon-cognito

I have a Cognito user pool, an app set up and a resource server set up.  We do not want to use the hosted UI to log in and I am trying from the back end to authorize with Oauth 2.0 with a user name and password and send the token back to the front end to use with api gateway calls.  I am using c# and the provided SDK does not allow for the right scope, so I am trying the manual oauth2 method of logging in, but nothing I have tried is working.

Edit:
I have gotten a bit further today trying to use postman,  however, I am getting the error: unsupported_grant_type with the following setup:

[image: Postman Setup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, this is not supported without hosted UI. Basically, you can not expect [AdminInitiateAuth](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-authentication-flow.html#amazon-cognito-user-pools-server-side-authentication-flow) to include custom scopes in the `access_token`.

This is not a limitation in .NET SDK. This is a limitation in Cognito itself.

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59923555) answer, someone can argue that this the intended behaviour.

> Signing in via initiate Auth or admin initiate Auth is not via the Oauth endpoints so the Oauth custom scopes will not be included in the token.

Also this issue has been mentioned in different other SDKs/Libs like: [android sdk](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/issues/684), [Amplify JS](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/3732) as well. Several issues are mentioned in this [comment](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net-extensions-cognito/issues/42#issuecomment-1087222470).

Maybe you could try to use `id_token` along with Lambda Authorizers as a workaround.

Comment: I may have to try that.  It is not ideal because we should be using the Access Token from the front ends.

Comment: How would I identify a user in our system with this id_token?

Comment: `id_token` is a JWT. We can decode that and extract the `sub` claim, which represents the _user id_. Or you can rely on `email` claim.

Comment: @MAkin could you pls elaborate the question bit more with your requirement? Specially in terms of user permission/roles etc ?  I asked that because, we might be able to use, user groups in cognito based on the requirement. User groups are included in the _access token_.

Comment: To authorize with Cognito via api gateway, you have to set up a resource server and add that scope to the app client, however, that scope does not populate in the access token unless you use the "hosted ui".  Unless I am missing something somewhere.   Without the scope it will not authenticate.